# Element matrix multiplication representation

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Matrix element by element multiplication defined :
$C=A*B$
$c_{ij}=a_{ij}b_{ij}$

Is this multiplication can be represented with stardant matrix multiplication or Kronecker product ?

Comment: The Hadamard product $A\odot B$ is a sub-matrix of $A\otimes B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matrix multiplication can neither be represented as a standard multiplication nor using a Kronecker product.

It is instead known as a [Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (or Schur) product.

Comment: Or as the Schur product.

Comment: Yes indeed, @Chris Godsil. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper by
Charles R. Johnson and Peter M. Nylen  titled
``Hadamard product submultiplicativity of certain induced norms ''
Linear and Multilinear Algebra, 48:2, 165-178

that describes this, 
there it also says the topic was also covered in

``Largest Singular Value Submultiplicativity''
SIAM journal for Matrix Analysis, 12, 1-6.